# Creating a user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

When I try to create a user, `up.SamAccountName` will throw a

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException

My code:

```
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "some ip"))
{
    using (var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
    {
        up.SamAccountName = "user";
        up.EmailAddress = "some email";
        up.SetPassword("abcde@@12345!~");
        up.Enabled = true;
        up.ExpirePasswordNow();
        up.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("We did it.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: [How to almost everything in active directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#35)
It has as the title suggests almost everything and it helped me out a great deal when I was lost in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your exception should contain **more details** in an `.InnerException` - what does it say?

My *guess* would be: you're not using a **unique** `SamAccountName` - that name **must be** unique within the whole domain (and has a maxlength of 20 characters).  Can you try with a more random user name and see if it works?

Comment: InnerException says null haha, and it doesn't matter what username i put there.

Comment: @Yooouuri: does that exception you get *at least* have a **message**? What does it say?

Comment: {"De gebruikersnaam of het wachtwoord is onjuist.\r\n"} The username or password is invalid..

Comment: @Yooouuri: since you're already setting `ExpirePasswordNow` - could you try to create the user without a specific password? Or maybe that password you're using doesn't match your password criteria? (length, complexity etc.)

Comment: it throws an exception on SamAccountName, but ill try.

Comment: without up.SetPassword & up.ExpirePasswordNow it still throws an exception